# Array Query after finding the object MongoDB with node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5abce64d86d3289de052a639"),
        "username" : "doggy",
        "email" : "doggy@sabanciuniv.edu",
        "password" : "iLoveDoggy",
        "friends" : [ 
            {
                "username" : "djBackend",
                "status" : "2"
            }, 
            {
                "username" : "eggroid",
                "status" : "1"
            }, 
            {
                "username" : "Berk",
                "status" : "2"
            }
        ]
    },
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab90f25e7708f0f4455075a"),
    "username" : "guiBOI",
    "email" : "iDoGUI@sabanciuniv.edı",
    "password" : "animeKeyfisi",
    "friends" : [ 
        {
            "username" : "djBackend",
            "status" : "2"
        }, 
        {
            "username" : "eggroid",
            "status" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I have the format of JSON as storage in my mongoDB. What i would like to do is that find the username with "doggy" which is

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5abce64d86d3289de052a639"),
            "username" : "doggy",
            "email" : "doggy@sabanciuniv.edu",
            "password" : "iLoveDoggy",
            "friends" : [ 
                {
                    "username" : "djBackend",
                    "status" : "2"
                }, 
                {
                    "username" : "eggroid",
                    "status" : "1"
                }, 
                {
                    "username" : "Berk",
                    "status" : "2"
                }
            ]
        }
```

and change its status of username named as "eggroid" "1" to "2". I have been trying it with db.collection.findAndModify(document); but no success, i am new to mongoDB so sorry if this is a newbie question but i have been struggling ober 3 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $ ([positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/))

```
db.collection.update({username: "doggy", "friends.username" : "eggroid"}, { $set: { "friends.$.status": 2} })
```

Based on your filtering conditions (first parameter) MongoDB will figure out which item of nested array you want to update (works only for first matched subdocument)